# MySQL Replication - replication issues; procedures registered on master not giving same result on slave in MySQL 5.5.20

Tags: mysql, replication

I am not able to replicate procedures registered in the Master to the Slave in MySQL 5.5.20

The Procedure is registered on the Master and can be seen on Slave. However, results fetched using the same tables are different.

Anyone know how can I debug and solve this???

Comment: Have you manually run the procedure on the slave?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay attention on you replica configuration, first of all it is a statement-based o row-based replica?

Probably you run an "unsafe" statement in you master server so the slave can't apply same statement in deterministic mode.

Check the master error.log for warnings like:

```
[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary 
log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT.
```

For more information: [Determination of Safe and Unsafe Statements in Binary Logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html)